# Javascript to loop through all asp:Hyperlink controls on a page, and hide them

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net

I have a master page which has a DIV with asp:Hyperlink controls functioning as the menu for the site.

When I'm on a certain page if (document.title = 'Certain Page'), I want javascript which will loop through all asp:hyperlink controls on the page and hide them (i.e. set to not visible).  I know I could probably do this on the server side with less effort, but I'd rather do it via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to decorate your `asp:Hyperlink`'s with a `class` that can be used to identify them on the client-side (you could also infer this from the control-id generation, but that would be more prone to errors, especially since ASP.NET 4.0 offers some alternatives).

One these links have a common/consistent class then you would just need to have the Javascript select items with that class and hide them.  Depending on your choice of client-side libraries (or lack thereof) this could be something like a simple line of jQuery (assuming your `asp:Hyperlinks` have `class="aspLink"`): `$('.aspLink').hide();`

Comment: what if i used a naming convention with my links, like linkMenu and linkProfile...is there any way I could match on asp control id name instead of using class?

Comment: you *could*, but it's a case where using a `class` is a better fit.  Looping through elements and manually examining their `id` is likely to be much less performant than using classes (although some browsers will likely do just that).

Comment: sure you can with jquery. For all hyperlinks (that will be rendered on <a>) ID terminated by linkMenu you can use $('a[id$linkMenu]').hide(); for links containing use $('a[id*linkMenu]').hide(); etc

Comment: Sorry I made a typo I meant $('a[id$=linkMenu]').hide() and $('a[id*=linkMenu]').hide();

Comment: @FrenchilnLa -- good point, provided jQuery is available (I know, I used it in my example too :P )

Answer (score 1):

The only way to determine for sure what was an asp:hyperlink as opposed to a regular hyperlink `<a>` tag is going to be to add a class to all your asp:hyperlink tags. You could then use some jquery like

```
$('.AspLink').remove();
```

If you have some other way to determine that they are uniquely asp:hyperlink tags you can use some other jquery expression similarly. So if you have your `<div>` and know all links in the div are asp:hyperlink you can just use

```
$('#MyMenu a').remove();
```

Comment: what if i used a naming convention with my links, like linkMenu and linkProfile...is there any way I could match on asp control id name instead of using class?

Comment: Potentially, maybe this will give you some ideas. Use this http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ for general search or this for your IDs http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Assign an ID to the outer DIV, then use something like follows:

```
var childs = document.getElementById("outerDiv").childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<childs.length;i++) {
   if(childs[i].tagName == "a") childs[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

But actually you can do the same in code-behind of the master page.

Comment: this wouldn't scale to handle nested elements; you would need to at least do this recursively--and then, depending on the OP's exact scenario, this may hide `<a>`'s which were not generated from `asp:Hyperlink` controls.

Comment: The benefit is the performance, I made it on the assumption of the given information: asp:Hyperlink inside the DIV.